# Trusting self signed certificates for Elasticsearch SSL configuration

Tags: ssl, elasticsearch, self-signed

I am using search guard to enable TLS/SSL over Elastic Search. The certificate that I am using are demo certificates provided by search guard.
The cert chain has got 3 certificates "ROOT CA", "ROOT Signing CA", "Node Certificate". When the client tries to access the elasticsearch REST API It gets an error
**"The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."** which is fine. To avoid this I added the "ROOT CA" and "ROOT Signing CA" to my local machine's trusted certificate store. Even after this the error persists.

I don't want to override ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback method, because it is mentioned [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/working-with-certificates.html) in the first paragraph that if the certificates are trusted then no changes are required from code side.

So my question is: Can I trust those certificates by any means? This is for development purposes, in the production we will be using certificates signed by authorized CA only